# Add widgets inside pushButton?

Tags: python, pyside, maya, pyside2

Hi I’m still relatively new to PySide2 and setting up some UIs inside maya . 
Is it possible to have a QPushButton which has other widgets as children ?

For instance I want to make a pair of QPushButtona side by side that turn each other toggled on and  off when either is clicked , each should have a spinBox inside them . The spinBox is disabled if it’s parent button is ‘off’

I was going to make a simple button class which can toggle it’s counterpart off , so that bit is straightforward , but I can’t see a way to put the spinBox inside it too, maybe something I’ve missed ? Can I add a layout to my button then add widgets inside ?

Thanks for any help

Ben

Comment: Why don't you simply use a `QSpinBox`?

Comment: I am using a QSpinBox . I want to put one associated / inside a button that can be toggled on or off . My question wasn’t about the spin boxes necessarily , but whether I can have widgets parented to a button

Comment: I'm sorry, INSIDE a pushbutton?? This widget sounds terrifying! Can you include some image example?

Comment: I’ll post an image later. Maybe a better description would be , a clickable ‘group box’ that contains a spinBox . When you click on the group box it toggles on , and toggles off another one . Basically it’s like have a radial button type behaviour , where I can choose which spinBox to be available to the user . I wanted it inside some sort of clickable rectangle , hence my instinct to have a button .

Comment: Cool,since I don't see any code I'll wait for the image then.

Comment: My brain has exploded too with the nesting things, xd. a picture could defintly help to see what you want to

Comment: Hi , sorry for the delay . Here’s a mock up I made in Krita to show you what I want. The spinBoxes are inside rectangular borders / boxes which are clickable , when you toggle one, the other disables . This was why I asked about whether a widget such as a spinBox could be visually ‘inside’ a button. https://imgur.com/gallery/I2HES5E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wondering to see if it was possible, and it looks like yes, you can use a button and nest another widget in it. I thought you would have to jump through a lot more hoops to get it working properly, but it's not too bad.

You can make the buttons checkable, then use a `QButtonGroup` to make the buttons behave like a `QRadioButton`. Though unlike a `QGroupBox` you need to handle the enabled state of the spin box yourself. So here's a working example:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class ButtonContainer(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ButtonContainer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumHeight(50)  # Set minimum otherwise it will collapse the container
        self.setCheckable(True)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
                border: none;
            }

            QPushButton:checked {
                background-color: green;
            }
        """)


class Win(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Win, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 0)

        # 1st groupbox and spinbox.
        self.container_layout1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.container1 = ButtonContainer()
        self.container1.setChecked(True)
        self.container1.setLayout(self.container_layout1)
        self.container1.clicked.connect(self.on_container_clicked)

        self.spinbox1 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent=self.container1)  # Set the container as its parent so that we can use `findChildren` in the event later.
        self.container_layout1.addWidget(self.spinbox1)

        # 2nd groupbox and spinbox.
        self.container_layout2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.container2 = ButtonContainer()
        self.container2.setLayout(self.container_layout2)
        self.container2.clicked.connect(self.on_container_clicked)

        self.spinbox2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent=self.container2)  # Set the container as its parent so that we can use `findChildren` in the event later.
        self.container_layout2.addWidget(self.spinbox2)

        # Group buttons together so they behave as radio buttons.
        self.button_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.button_group.addButton(self.container1)
        self.button_group.addButton(self.container2)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.container1)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.container2)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        # Trigger event to set initial enabled states.
        self.on_container_clicked()

    def on_container_clicked(self):
        for container in [self.container1, self.container2]:  # Loop through all of our custom containers.
            for child in container.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget):  # Get all of the container's children.
                child.setEnabled(container.isChecked())  # Set its enabled state based if the container is checked.


win = Win()
win.show()
```

You technically don't really need to subclass the `QPushButton` though it makes it easier to recycle the code.

[image: Example]

Comment: If this has answered your question please accept it so others know it has been resolved. Otherwise you should edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: Sorry - is that the green tick , relatively new to the app

Comment: ^ Yes the green tick! Glad to hear the solution helped out.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use a `QGroupBox` since you can already make it checkable and add items inside it. When the groupbox's checkbox is ticked off, it will disable any of its contents. So most of the framework is already there. The only gotcha is instead of a checkbox, you want it to work like a `QRadioButton` so that the other disables. We can put some simple logic to handle that:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class Win(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Win, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 0)

        # 1st groupbox and spinbox.
        self.spinbox1 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()

        self.group_layout1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.group_layout1.addWidget(self.spinbox1)

        self.groupbox1 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("1")
        self.groupbox1.setCheckable(True)
        self.groupbox1.setLayout(self.group_layout1)
        self.groupbox1.toggled.connect(self.on_groupbox_toggled)

        # 2nd groupbox and spinbox.
        self.spinbox2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()

        self.group_layout2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.group_layout2.addWidget(self.spinbox2)

        self.groupbox2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("2")
        self.groupbox2.setCheckable(True)
        self.groupbox2.setChecked(False)
        self.groupbox2.setLayout(self.group_layout2)
        self.groupbox2.toggled.connect(self.on_groupbox_toggled)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.groupbox1)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.groupbox2)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def on_groupbox_toggled(self, enabled):
        # Force user to not be able to uncheck it.
        if not enabled:
            self.sender().setChecked(True)

        # Block signals so this function doesn't get triggered by other groupbox.
        self.groupbox1.blockSignals(True)
        self.groupbox2.blockSignals(True)

        # Check off other groupbox.
        if self.sender() == self.groupbox1:
            self.groupbox2.setChecked(False)
        else:
            self.groupbox1.setChecked(False)

        # Restore signals.
        self.groupbox1.blockSignals(False)
        self.groupbox2.blockSignals(False)


win = Win()
win.show()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: That’s a great way, I’d still love to able to not have the checkboxes, and have a clickable pane , but for my current goals this will work . Thanks

Comment: Also with a style sheet edit - this is looking great thanks for code

Comment: I think that's possible but you would have to start sub-classing and may have to deal with more overhead.